excel group column highlight matching values
I have a alphabetized dataset of:



Column A
Column B




D47058V212B
9/23/2024 20:56


D47058V214
9/23/2024 20:56


D47058V29
9/23/2024 20:57


D47065V24
9/23/2024 23:02


D47089V215A
9/23/2024 23:37


D47091V214
9/23/2024 23:40


D4712426
9/24/2024 0:29


D47138V28
9/23/2024 22:52


D5485911
9/24/2024 3:39



I'd like to have each group by the first 6 matching characters. So all the values that start with D47089 are blue highlighted. all the D47091 are green highlighted ect. Having it rotate between 3 different colors all the way down the column. (colors aren't important, just that they rotate for easy reading).
Is there a way to have excel do this automatically without me having to create separate conditional rules for each possible iteration of the first 6 characters?

Basic logic is the same as Scot's, but using a named formula:

To accommodate future entries easily, I would recommend inserting table for the data

In Table tab clear "Banded Rows" (and other options if needed)

With a named formula you need to modify it only in one place - so create a named formula, for example, colIndex with
=LAMBDA(a, MOD(XMATCH(LEFT(a,6), UNIQUE(LEFT(Table1[Column1],6))), 3))


Select all data rows in the table with top left cell being the active cell, add conditional formatting as shown below (with your colors :)

Formula for formatting is =colIndex($A2)=0




You will need 3 rules.
=MOD(MATCH(LEFT($A1,6),UNIQUE(LEFT($A$1:$A$9,6)),0)-1,3)+1=1
=MOD(MATCH(LEFT($A1,6),UNIQUE(LEFT($A$1:$A$9,6)),0)-1,3)+1=2
=MOD(MATCH(LEFT($A1,6),UNIQUE(LEFT($A$1:$A$9,6)),0)-1,3)+1=3

Then associate the color desired to each:

